Quick way to reclassify raster into positive, negative, and zero classes
I have quite a few rasters I want to reclassify into three classes (positive, zero, and negative). I'm aware of the reclassify tool, but just wondering what the quickest way is to reclassify them. They are all floating points but have varying max and min values (e.g., 173.84 to -255.28; -2.0 to 2.0 etc etc.
I don't mind what the output values are, just need three distinct classes as it's taking a while to go through each layer individually with using reclassify and adjusting their respective max and min values. Using ArcGIS Pro.

Are you doing this manually, as in you are running the reclassify tool manually? If so why not use modelbuilder to automate this all?

Right click the Reclassify tool and see if it supports batch processing.
